# Save date in form tag

Tags: reactjs

I have an application what saves data from 2 forms clicking on one button `save`. The data saves ok, but i have issues with one field:

```js
  

   <Form.Item
        {...field}
         name={[field.name, "date"]}
             fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "date"]}
           rules={[
              {
          required: false,
         message: "Missing date"
       }
      ]}
      className="sub-event-date"
        >
     <Range />
   </Form.Item>
```

When i click on `save` button i don't get data from the field above. So here: `console.log(subFormRef.current.getFieldValue());` i should get and data from the date picker.

**Question: How to solve the above issue?**
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-keller-pys5s?file=/src/OuterForm.js:576-624

Comment: Click on AddField is giving error

Comment: @RaghvenderKataria, on my side it works ok, could you check again, please and let me know if works. Thanks

Comment: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Its giving me this error on CodeSandbox

Comment: @RaghvenderKataria, now should work. It works?

Comment: @RaghvenderKataria, could you tell me if the  code now works?